# filling a 2D array with pairs of random numbers

Tags: c++

I am trying to use an array to see if the randomly generated number is valid before putting it into the 2D array. This should allow me to have a maximum of 2 of each number therefore only having pairs of numbers. But it doesn't work.

```cpp
void getDeck(int deck[ROW][COL])
{
    srand(time(0));
    int twoCards[8] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int num = 0;
    for(int row = 0; row < ROW; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < COL; col++)
        {
            if(col % 4 == 0)
            {
                cout << endl;
            }

            num = rand()%8+1;
            twoCards[num - 1]= twoCards[num - 1] + 1;
            if(twoCards[num - 1] < 2)
            {
                deck[row][col] = num;
            }
            else
            {
                while(twoCards[num - 1] > 2)
                {
                    num = rand()%8+1;
                }
                twoCards[num - 1] = twoCards[num - 1] + 1;
                deck[row][col] = num;
            }


            cout << deck[row][col] << "    ";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `twoCards[num - 1]= twoCards[num - 1]++` leads to *undefined behavior*. What does your text-books say about the `++` operators? Do you really need the assignment?

Comment: I changed it from ++ to +1 and it almost works now. But there is sometimes a set of 3 and a lone number with the rest all being pairs. I am not sure why this is.

Comment: The right way to generate a random sequence of non-repeating values is to generate an ordered sequence of those values, then `std::shuffle` it. Doing it the way you do, by generating random values and discarding those already used before, is inefficient. Imagine how many times you'd have to keep rolling the dice in order to pick the 8th value, when the other 7 are already taken.

Comment: You check `if(twoCards[num - 1] < 2)` in one place, and `while(twoCards[num - 1] > 2)` in another. These checks are not complementary - the second one allows `twoCards[num - 1] == 2`, that is, it allows picking a number that was already used once, the second time. Did you mean it this way? It's not entirely clear what this function is trying to achieve.